# What is the default username and password for Ubuntu 12.04 via Startup Disk Creator?

Tags: password, live-environment

I just installed **ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso** to my 1GB flash drive via **Startup Disk Creator** on Ubuntu 12.04. Then, I tried to boot it on my system.

The problem is that it was asking me for username and password.

I tried "ubuntu" with blank password but it didn't work.

The problem has never happened when I installed the same iso file via [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) on Windows.

Note: There's no option to make passwords in Startup Disk Creator.

[image: Make Startup Disk]

Comment: Default username is **ubuntu** , you are right , but there is no password .

Comment: Did you choose a username/password when creating? Try ubuntu:ubuntu...

Comment: Like izx said, did you select any user and password when you created the live usb?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no option to do that. :( See screenshot above.

Comment: if this is a duplicat where is the correct question and answer. 10.04 is different from 12.04 so the 10.04 question IMHO doesn't count

Answer (score 0):

Try your ubuntu username and password in which you created the .iso